# Which driver do I need to Install for my gt540M if i want to use bumblebee?

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I have the choice of the Nvidia 185 driver and the experimental one.
My Laptop is an Acer aspire 5750G with intel sandyBridge i5.

I just installed Bumblebee.Then I enabled the Card, and ran "nvidia-settings". A window saying:

> You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run nvidia-xconfig as root), and restart the X server.

But it seems, nvidia-xconfig is not installed on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

The current nvidia driver (`nvidia-current`) in Natty is version 270.41.06 which does [not support your GT 540M](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/270.41.06/README/supportedchips.html). 280.13 [does support it though](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/280.13/README/supportedchips.html). You can get it by installing the [ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

As for Bumblebee, see [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969#36936) for the latest installation instructions. After installing that version, you can get nvidia-settings to run with:

```
nvidia-settings -c :8
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also download the latest version from the NVidia's website:

[Nvidia - Linux Display Driver - x86](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-280.13-driver.html)

To install it you better restart your computer in the console mode, remove everything you have from the old driver and reinstall the new one.

To remove the old driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

To install the new driver (the one you downloaded from the website), considering that you're into the directory where the installation file is:

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-280.13.run
```

After that you'll need to restart your computer:

```
sudo reboot now
```

Now your nvidia driver might be updated :-)

Comment: Not applicable for Optimus laptops, it breaks 3D

Comment: I second this. I don't want to downvote because the author probably meant no arm, but it's a pain to recover from what following these instructions would do to your ubuntu.